# duplicate Maven projects importing in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, svn

one simple application in my local (this project i check outed  from SVN), project 1. when i was trying to importing 
the project twice Maven project imported .

the structure of the project is something like

project1
 sub project_1
 sub project_2

when i was importing the maven Existing  project below structure its displaying

project1
  sub project_1
  sub project_2

sub-project_1
sub-project_2.

sub-project_1 and sub-project_2 projects are twice when importing Maven project.

how we will override the twice Maven Project,

Any clues?

Thanks.